# How to backup data on Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, insert

I have an Oracle database, which was made using Oracle 11g. I manually created tables and entered data using the GUI. Now I want to obtain 'insert into' queries using those inserted data.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you mean creating a duplicate table from an existing one?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (FIELD1, FIELD2, FIELD3) VALUES ('
       mt.FIELD1 || ', ' ||
       mt.FIELD2 || ', ' ||
       mt.FIELD3 || ');'
  FROM MY_TABLE mt;
```

Modify as needed for your tables.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

For example, Allrounds' PL/SQL Developer can export tables as SQL scripts.